# Is there anything "bad" data preservation-wise about zipping a big dir of subdirs and tons of files?

Tags: backup, zip, 7-zip, archiving, file-corruption

I have a "gold backup base" directory tree of 48 GB of data containing "11 411 Files, 1 054 Folders".

Since USB/ROBOCOPY/Windows takes forever to transfer many little files to all my external backup disks, I have now 7-zipped that whole dirtree to a new .7z file which I will transfer to my backup devices as one single file.

But can this cause any issues? Can a single big file like that become completely corrupted if a single little atom moves on the storage media, locking me out forever from all my old data, whereas the "straight" directory structure (NTFS) would only cause one file out of them all to go corrupted?

Or am I fundamentally confused with this thinking? I'm just trying to make sure I'm not making the worst possible decision which I will deeply regret in the future.

Comment: Yes a file can get corrupted for some reason, but so does a filesystem (although I have to admit that I have never seen an **entire** filesystem being affected). In fact I have had once the case of a big archive file that I could no longer open... This doesn't directly answer the question but have you considered doing incremental backups? The initial backup would still be very long to complete, but in the next backups only the files that have changed would be transfered.

Comment: @PierU I basically did an incremental backup to this directory tree on each backup media, but after combining them all and creating a "new base", I opted to 7zip it instead of facing the long initial loading over of the new files. (Yes, I could have been more efficient, but am not a ROBOCOPY expert.)

Comment: if you have 100 small buckets of water, and one of them develops a hole in the bottom, you still have 99 buckets of water. if you pour all the water into a single large bucket however, and it develops a hole, you are left with nothing. Long ago, I was trying to rebuild a friends system, and backed up all his profile info, but in order to save time, I used a multipart archive where each chunck would fit on a DVD so I could rebuild the OS. unfortunately, the 5th chunk came out bad (could be DVD or the archive itself, no way to know) and as a result, none of the chuncks 1-4 could be extracted.

Comment: so what is your backup rotation strategy? your risk here really goes down if you save perhaps the 5 most recent backups. it sounds like you save backups in multiple places already, so your biggest vulnerability is that the archive becomes corrupt before you copy it to your backup devices. if you save several prior versions of the backup, you are likely to only lose a day or two of changes. if you really need more than that you are probably looking for a version control system, that would have its own backup approach.

Comment: I am upvoting for incremental backup with some versionning system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that if enough of a compressed archive becomes corrupted that some or all of the data can be lost.  However, I dont find that to be a common occurrence.  That being said, if your backup drive fails completely, then it is possible that you have lost everything on the drive, regardless of what method you chose.

You need to make your own decision on what is important to you.  Space saving and convenience versus *possible* data loss.  Personally, I do compress my backups and have never had an issue.

Just be sure after you make a backup, to ***TEST*** restoration.  This is one of the most common failure points in backup strategies.  Ive seen companies lose all their data, as they were not backing up properly and only discovered the issue *after* trying to recover the data.

If the data is important, make multiple backups and store them in different locations and do occasional restoration tests.

Comment: I do make several (5 on hard disks and 2 on flash memory) redundant copies indeed, but all except for one of the HDDs are now 10 years old and it frightens me if they all would die at once or until I realized. But they are also not exactly given away for free, and I have to save money etc.

Comment: Flash drive is a bad idea for longer term storage if these are disconnected from power. NAND memory 'bleeds data', depending on quality of the NAND it may be a slow process but eventually it does happen.

Comment: As long as the backup is regularly updated on the flash drive, the risk loosing data that way is very low. However, backuping 48GB of small file to a 10 years old flash drive (I assume not a SSD) is indeed an awful experience...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible an archive can become corrupted to a degree where it can not be unpacked. You wouldn't be the first to discover this and it illustrates the saying *one* backup is *no* backup. The same goes for encrypted backups and the same goes for compressed disk image etc..

It may not be common (how would one define common?) but it happens more often than one might think. I know of plenty cases where a data recovery company is asked to recover the data for clients discovering their backups turned out to be worthless.

It is exactly as you suspect. Say the storage medium on which the backup archive resides develops a local issue (chunks of bad sectors for example) it may render the entire archive useless where in case you backed up individual files only 1, or 20, or even 150 files might have been effected.

Comment: Darnit! This is very bad news for me. I'm pretty much going to have to revert to using loose files if this is true...

Comment: and even worse (in case of a corrupted archive), is that while many/most of the files may be fully intact, the compression changed their binary headers and footers and encoding properties, so data recovery tools that use file carving would not be able to identify the files for recovery (well, unless they were specifically written to understand that archive format and compression algorithm which is unlikely, though many will recognize the exterior [broken] archive file).

Comment: @FrankThomas, true however I once had a lucky break. Don't know how or why, but .. https://www.disktuna.com/corrupt-7-zip-7z-archive-a-lucky-break/